# XHR2 allow origin - can this be faked?

Tags: ajax, security, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, cors

With regards to the way resources accessed over XHR2/CORS can block the request unless it came from a whitelisted domain:

- which header is read to determine the referrer domain - is it the standard HTTP_REFERRER?
- could someone send a request pretending to be from another domain somehow?

I'm aware CORS is not a reliable means of securing data - I ask only as a point of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

The header that is read is `Origin`. As any HTTP header it can be faked. The idea behind COSR is to enable sending data, while still securing the user / preventing abusing of user session. The cross-domain requests are forbidden to protect the user, not the server.

The attacker should both send the request pretending this is another domain AND send the cookies the user has. And this is not something you can achieve via `XSS` alone - you have to steal the cookie and send the request on your own. But you cannot steal the cookie for site A from site B. If A however accepts request from any domain, via XSS on B you can trick the user's browser to send request to A, the browser will send the cookies and you can read the response back.

Answer (score 0):

The `Origin` header contains the requesting domain.

This browser is in complete control of this header, and it cannot be faked. The browser controls this header on behalf of the user, and user's cannot override the value in the JS code.

Note that I said "the browser"; as with any HTTP request, the user could craft a curl request with any `Origin` header. But this has limited use as an attack vector, since the hacker would have to trick a valid user into issuing the correct curl request, which is unlikely.